# the loop in magic 8 ball has a bug

Tags: c, function, while-loop

I'm trying to make a Magic 8 Ball program but my loop has a bug.

1. If you play again, the loop messes up and behaves like you were hitting enter all the time for about three cycles until it will work again.
2. Also, there is a delay when you enter you question. You have to hit enter twice to get the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ans(int x);
int main()
{
    system("color 0A");
    srand(time(0));
    int num,i;

    do{

    char question[100] = {" "};

    num = rand()%10;

    puts("MAGIC 8 BALL!");
    puts("Press Enter When Ready.");
    getch();
    system("cls");
    puts("Input Yes or No questions only!");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%s",&question);
    getch();
    printf("\nTHE ANSWER | ");
    ans(num);
    getch();
    system("cls");
    printf("Press any key to try again.\nPress [x] to Exit.");

    if(getch()=='x'){
        system("cls");
        break;
    }
    system("cls");
    }while(1);
}
void ans(int x){
    switch(x){
        case 1 : printf("YES!");break;
        case 2 : printf("NO!");break;
        case 3 : printf("It's a thumbs down.");break;
        case 4 : printf("Positive!");break;
        case 5 : printf("As I see it Yes.");break;
        case 6 : printf("Certainly!");break;
        case 7 : printf("Negative!");break;
        case 8 : printf("Don't Count on it.");break;
        case 9 : printf("You don't want to know, trust me.");break;
        case 10: printf("I can't say right now.");break;
        default : printf("Cannot be determined right now");break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you eliminate the second `getch()` in your main function

Comment: Note also that `num = rand()%10;` gives you values from 0 to 9, not 1 to 10.  You might adjust your switch statement to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed your problem. Added comments explaining. Hopefully I caught everything. Tested the program, and it works fine now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_QUESTION            1000
#define STATEMENT_AMOUNT        10

int random_num_generator();
void statement_picker(int x);

int main(void) {

    char temp;
    int rand;

    // Your while condition really just needs to be scanning 1 character.
    // No point in scanning the entire string, because we don't even use the string
    // The scanning jus tells us when to start the loop again
    while (1) {

        // The introduction of our program
        system("cls");
        printf("MAGIC 8 BALL!\n");
        printf("Press Enter When Ready.\n");
        getch();

        // Asking user to enter in their question
        system("cls");
        printf("What is your question?\n");
        printf("Only enter yes or no questions!\n");
        // You have to flush (aka clear) stdin. Because it uses your previous inputs
        // automatically. For example, if you type "I am the best?". The program will not work
        // properly for num_of_words - 1 iterations. So 4 - 1. Will not work properly for
        // 3 iterations
        // Also you don't need to scan in the word, because we don't really care what question
        // the user typed. You can save some memory by only scanning in a single character.
        // We only use scanf to give a real magic 8 ball experience by stopping and waiting
        // for the user to type their question.
        scanf("%c", &temp);
        fflush(stdin);

        // Generating a random number
        printf("The answer you seek: ");
        rand = random_num_generator();
        statement_picker(rand);

        // So I noticed here you cls, but you cls without waiting. This the user won't
        // be able to read your answer in time. So you should cls after you ask the user
        // to quit, or have a timer. Commented a timber for you below. You also need to
        // include the unistd.h library to use the sleep function. Just uncomment it
        // in the #includes section if you want the timer.
        // sleep(10);
        // system("cls");

        // Asking the user if they want to try again
        printf("Would you like to ask another question?\n");
        printf("Press [x] to quit\n");
        printf("Press any other character to continue\n");
        scanf("%c", &temp);
        if (temp == 'x') break;

        // Flush at the end too, just in case the person types multiple things rather than
        // one characters
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    system("cls");
    return 0;
}

// Generates a random number between 0 - 10.
/* I noticed in your switch statement you start at case 1. You should start at case 0,
 * because you are using the modulus operator Just for example, if rand generators 30 and
 * you have 10 cases you will be doing (30 % 10) which is equal to 0 because 10 goes into 10,
 * 3 times with no remainders If you really want to start your switch case at 1,
 * then you have to plus one to the return value in random_num_generator
 */
int random_num_generator() {

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    return rand() % STATEMENT_AMOUNT;
}

// Picks a statement and prints it, depending on the value of x
void statement_picker(int x){
    switch(x){
        // Your case should start at 0, not 1 because you will never print out case 0
        // the way you had it before.
        case 0 : printf("YES!\n");break;
        case 1 : printf("NO!\n");break;
        case 2 : printf("It's a thumbs down.\n");break;
        case 3 : printf("Positive!\n");break;
        case 4 : printf("As I see it Yes.\n");break;
        case 5 : printf("Certainly!\n");break;
        case 6 : printf("Negative!\n");break;
        case 7 : printf("Don't Count on it.\n");break;
        case 8 : printf("You don't want to know, trust me.\n");break;
        case 9 : printf("I can't say right now.\n");break;
        // No need for default because you'll never get to it
        // (just because of how we implemented this software)
        // default : printf("Cannot be determined right now");break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void ans(int x);
int main()
{
srand(time(0));
int num,i;

do{
    num = rand()%10;
    char question[1000];
    puts("MAGIC 8 BALL!");
    puts("Press Enter When Ready.");
    puts("Input Yes or No questions only!\n");
    scanf("%s",question);
    printf("\nTHE ANSWER | ");
    ans(num);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Press any key to try again.\nPress [x] to Exit.\n\n");
    char c = getchar();
    c=getchar();
    if(c=='x'){
        break;
    }
}while(1);
}
void ans(int x){
switch(x){
    case 1 : printf("YES!");break;
    case 2 : printf("NO!");break;
    case 3 : printf("It's a thumbs down.");break;
    case 4 : printf("Positive!");break;
    case 5 : printf("As I see it Yes.");break;
    case 6 : printf("Certainly!");break;
    case 7 : printf("Negative!");break;
    case 8 : printf("Don't Count on it.");break;
    case 9 : printf("You don't want to know, trust me.");break;
    case 10: printf("I can't say right now.");break;
    default : printf("Cannot be determined right now");break;
}
}
```